# Mysql Select query - not able to limit records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a ranking table in which i have all players with their ranks.

```
id | rank | playername | is_available | ranking_name   | ranking_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |  1   | testname1   |     1        | australia open |   1
 2 |  2   | testname2   |     1        | australia open |   1
 3 |  3   | testname3   |     0        | australia open |   1
 4 |  4   | testname4   |     1        | australia open |   1
 5 |  1   | testname5   |     1        | japan open     |   2
```

This table is huge and for each ranking_id there can be more than 500 players.
Now every player can challenge a match to upper players x% above him. This x is set by superadmin. If x = 10, player "testname4" can challenge (num of players in a ranking_id * 10/100) = 4*10/100=0.4 round to 1. so testname4 can challenge one one player above him. But his above player "testname3" is not available. So he should be given next available player. I want the output like

```
//testname4 can challenge below players

id | rank | playername | status        |
--------------------------------------
 2 | 2    | testname2  |   available   |
 3 | 3    | testname3  | not available |
```

What i did:

```
 //testname4 wants to challenge. So i know his rank and other information

 $selectSql = mysql_query("SELECT * from rankingTable where ranking_id = 1 AND rank < 4");
```

This is giving me "testname1" record as well. how can i limit this ? And most biggest problem is i need to show the ranks in ascending order. Its not easy using order by here.

Comment: Do you need another where clause where "is_available = 1" as well if someone isn't availabe?

Comment: if i do that i wont get the players who are not available. I have to show them why is he being given an extra player. Their can be 3 players who are unavailable. So he should be given 4th player above him.

Comment: Ok, just wasn't 100% what was being asked so thought I would clarufy

Comment: Sure. Let me know if i was not enough descriptive. i will try to explain again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine the users to be challenged by performing a `SELECT ... WHERE is_available = 1 ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT ?`, then take `MIN(rank)` to find the highest ranked such user, then use that information to filter the table to users ranked between oneself and that user:

```sql
SELECT   rankingTable.*
FROM     rankingTable, (
  SELECT MIN(a_rank) AS lower, b_rank - 1 AS upper
  FROM (
    SELECT   a.rank AS a_rank, b.rank AS b_rank
    FROM     rankingTable AS a JOIN rankingTable AS b USING (ranking_id)
    WHERE    ranking_id = ?
         AND b.playername = ?
         AND a.rank < b.rank
         AND a.is_available = 1
    ORDER BY a.rank DESC
    LIMIT    ?
  ) AS ranks
) AS limits
WHERE    rank BETWEEN limits.lower AND limits.upper
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

See it (including determination of the number of users to be selected) on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3014/1/3).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. This worked for all the conditions. The only thing missing was one more where clause in the end, where ranking_id = 1. This worked great. Thanks a lot. +1 and tick to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding LIMIT 1 or LIMIT 0, 1 (beginning, how many records) to the end of your query

Comment: I cant put limit, what if the fetched player is not available ? i have have to show him the next available player.